# Partial matching GAE search API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, autocomplete, webapp2

Using the [GAE search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) is it possible to search for a partial match?

I'm trying to create autocomplete functionality where the term would be a partial word. eg.

> > b
>   > bui
>   > build

would all return "building".

How is this possible with GAE?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Though LIKE statement (partial match) is not supported in Full Text Search, but you could hack around it.

First, tokenize the data string for all possible substrings (hello = h, he, hel, lo, etc.)

```
def tokenize_autocomplete(phrase):
    a = []
    for word in phrase.split():
        j = 1
        while True:
            for i in range(len(word) - j + 1):
                a.append(word[i:i + j])
            if j == len(word):
                break
            j += 1
    return a
```

Build an index + document (Search API) using the tokenized strings

```
index = search.Index(name='item_autocomplete')
for item in items:  # item = ndb.model
    name = ','.join(tokenize_autocomplete(item.name))
    document = search.Document(
        doc_id=item.key.urlsafe(),
        fields=[search.TextField(name='name', value=name)])
    index.put(document)
```

Perform search, and walah!

```
results = search.Index(name="item_autocomplete").search("name:elo")
```

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-app-engine/partial-search-on-gae-with-search-api/

Comment: This works well.  I managed to mod Ferris's search.index function to automatically tokenize all textfields (one line change), and it "just works".  Just don't try to display said field to a user directly from the search result ;)

Comment: I've also added `name.lower()` because I had some strange problems with Russian language: if a token starts with a capital letter I was unable to find such token.

Comment: friendly note: the phrase is "voila!"

Comment: I have added the option to limit the length of sub-strings to avoid cases where search documents are increased too much. https://gist.github.com/AniX/33dddf2a1993ca941692

Answer (score 3):

just like @Desmond Lua answer, but with different tokenize function:

```
def tokenize(word):
  token=[]
  words = word.split(' ')
  for word in words:
    for i in range(len(word)):
      if i==0: continue
      w = word[i]
      if i==1: 
        token+=[word[0]+w]
        continue

      token+=[token[-1:][0]+w]

  return ",".join(token)
```

it will parse `hello world` as `he,hel,hell,hello,wo,wor,worl,world`.

it's good for light autocomplete purpose

Answer (score 2):

As described at [Full Text Search and LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790093/full-text-search-and-like-statement), no it's not possible, since the Search API implements full text indexing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem for typeahead control, and my solution is parse string to small part :

```
name='hello world'
name_search = ' '.join([name[:i] for i in xrange(2, len(name)+1)])
print name_search;
# -> he hel hell hello hello  hello w hello wo hello wor hello worl hello world
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

My version optimized: not repeat tokens

```
def tokenization(text):
    a = []
    min = 3
    words = text.split()
    for word in words:
        if len(word) > min:
            for i in range(min, len(word)):
                token = word[0:i]
                if token not in a:
                    a.append(token)
    return a
```

Comment: Please Add more description regarding your posted answer sir.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping in very late here.

But here is my well documented function that does tokenizing. The docstring should help you understand it well and use it. Good luck!!!

```
def tokenize(string_to_tokenize, token_min_length=2):
  """Tokenizes a given string.

  Note: If a word in the string to tokenize is less then
  the minimum length of the token, then the word is added to the list
  of tokens and skipped from further processing.
  Avoids duplicate tokens by using a set to save the tokens.
  Example usage:
    tokens = tokenize('pack my box', 3)

  Args:
    string_to_tokenize: str, the string we need to tokenize.
    Example: 'pack my box'.
    min_length: int, the minimum length we want for a token.
    Example: 3.

  Returns:
    set, containng the tokenized strings. Example: set(['box', 'pac', 'my',
    'pack'])
  """
  tokens = set()
  token_min_length = token_min_length or 1
  for word in string_to_tokenize.split(' '):
    if len(word) <= token_min_length:
      tokens.add(word)
    else:
      for i in range(token_min_length, len(word) + 1):
        tokens.add(word[:i])
  return tokens
```