# GAE Full Text Search: can only match exact word? how to search like contains(...)?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

Just tried GAE(1.7.7 Java) Full Text Search and found if the search string is `work`, surprisingly it will **not** match `working`, `worked`, or `hardworking`, `homework`, I'd like to know if i miss something in the API, i read the tutorial but did not found any document about this except plural match.

Thanks.

P.S. I tried unit test for search service, not in working environment.

Answer (score 0):

Tucked away in the docs (but unfortunately not in the table of operators), there is a '~' operator

To search for plural variants of an exact query, use the ~ operator:

~"car"  # searches for "car" and "cars"

Not sure how far that will get you.  Unfortunately thats about it.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview#Queries_on_Fields

There is so little documentation on this,but just having tried it, it just works on plurals.

One approach would be to do your own stemming on the words in the document, (though you wouldn't return that as the text ;-)  Then you could perform stemming on your search term and be able to match worked, working etc..

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but to follow up the previous answer, what you want to do is not possible with the basic API functions. The search API works on full-text searching principles. To get around this you can tokenise your searchable data pre-index and store this in a field with the relevant document.

See: [Partial matching GAE search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899083/partial-matching-gae-search-api/13171181#13171181)