# GAE Search API not normalizing search strings?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-search-api

When I search for something using the Search API I would expect the query strings to be normalized (i.e. accented letters to be turned into their non-accented counterparts).

So, for example, if I were to search for "azúcar", Search API would really search for "azucar".

Here's my Search handler code:

```
index = search.Index(name='index', namespace='namespace')
    results = index.search(
        query=Query(
            query_string=search_query,
            options=QueryOptions(
                limit=10,
                cursor=Cursor(),
                sort_options=SortOptions(
                    match_scorer=search.RescoringMatchScorer()
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Does Search API actually do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search API does not do this; see [Partial matching GAE search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899083/partial-matching-gae-search-api/13171181#13171181) and [GAE Full Text Search: can only match exact word? how to search like contains(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436572/gae-full-text-search-can-only-match-exact-word-how-to-search-like-contains) for similar discussions.

At my company we have implemented the mentioned tokenization approach and it seems to work reasonably well.  One approach for your problem would be to normalize to ASCII when you're doing the tokenization.  See [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string) for some how-tos on that.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Very helpful.