# Appengine Search API is not return results for few strings

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I'm having strange issue with Appengine Search API in Production. It is not returning results for few strings. I can replicate this issue on Appengine console as well as using application code. It works perfect in Local SDK.

Field Value is **j,1,4,1,5,j1,14,41,15,j14,141,415,j141,1415,j1415**

Appengine Search API Console:
[image: Appengine Search API Console]

(Actual string is j1415. Since Appengine doesn't support partial text search, i have tokenize the string. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13171181/783657)

When I enter query string as **141** or **415**, It is not returning any records. All other combinations (J14 or 41 or 1415 etc.) are returning the document.

[image]

Is this a bug in Search API or Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: It is possible the console is interpreting it as a number, which wouldn't match the text field. Type putting quotes around the number and see if that helps

Comment: Google cloud platform support team confirmed that this is an issue in . 
You can follow [this issue tracker thread](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13086) for updates.