# Simple query at App Engine Search not working

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, gae-search

I have the following data inside an index at Search API. The name and slug fields are TextFields.

```
Document Id         name                slug
5946158883012608    Configurations      configurations
4820258976169984    Customers           customers
6227633859723264    Sites               sites
```

I'm trying a lot of options of querystrings and can't get the right row.

My last tries:

- `index.search('config')`
- `index.search('~config')`
- `index.search('name:~config')`
- `index.search('slug:~config')`

If I try: `index.search('customers')` I receive one row. But if a remove the last `s`, then I receive no row.

Can someone please explain me why?

Regards,

Armando

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using `TextField` or `AtomField`? The above behaviour is expected with `AtomField`, but the above queries should work with `TextField` because Atom fields are not tokenized.

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to implement an autocomplete feature. I'll try it.

Comment: @atimothee not working. even with atomfield. :(

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13171181/2987899

Comment: Amazing! @atimothee .

Comment: Hey! I'm on the App Engine search team. Do give `index.search('slug:~customer')` a try--I'm not sure if it will work, but it might. We also may have other functionality that could help with your autocomplete use case. I'll check and find out more.

Comment: @WillHayworth I had already tried this, without success. The atimothee solution has worked well. ;) ty