# GAE Python Search API not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api

The following code:

```
from google.appengine.api import search
index = search.Index(name='members')
document = search.Document(
    fields=[
        search.TextField(name='full_name', value='sample text')
    ])       
index.put(document) 
results = index.search('full_name:tex')
logging.info(results)
```

returns:

```
search.SearchResults(number_found=0L)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Looks like GAE Search API is a Full Text search and does not support Partial Matching. Tokenized data based on the answer here:
[Partial matching GAE search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899083/partial-matching-gae-search-api)