# Does the GAE Search API support partial or prefix searches?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The [Google App Engine Search API docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) are a little light on the subject of partial or prefix searches. I understand that [stemming is supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/query_strings#Python_Stemming), but that's not quite what I want.

There are several other SO questions around this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13171181/125262), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791779/125262) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348861/how-to-implement-auto-suggestion-auto-complete-functionality-in-gae). It seems like partial-text search has been requested a number of times over several years.

Am I missing something in the GAE docs or is this still not supported?

Thanks for the sanity check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (more recent) 'acknowledged' [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11642&q=partial%20search&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) would seem to confirm that partial searches are still not supported.

Perhaps running [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html) on [Google Compute Engine](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/01/Deploy-Elasticsearch-on-Google-Compute-Engine.html) might work for your use case?

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'm not missing something after all. ES on GCE would work, but I kind of wish that GCP would provide a managed service like [AWS ElasticSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/). Oh well, maybe some day....