# Partial Matching of Search API GCP Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am working on a project that is on Google Standard App Engine.This requires the use of Search API functionality. However i could not find Search Api with partial text match. It is only gives full text search.
Is there a way for partial text match?
If not any custom tokenizer i can implement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the GAE Search API support partial or prefix searches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952112/does-the-gae-search-api-support-partial-or-prefix-searches)

Comment: Yup just wanted to confirm that there is no update on the same from gcp?